# Continous calling of recylerview notifyDataSetChanged blocks UI

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am working on chat application. 
I am using this [SoketLib](https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-client) library for sockets send and receive. Now after sending a message I have to update the chat list. Now the message sending/receiving frequency/speed is too high like. Like user is typing continuously.
so these list operation make the whole screen very slow after some time. I have debugged my socket code in detail. so it's not socket issue. it's just continuous calling of notifyDataSetChanged() method of recylerview.

```
  messagesAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
      if (messagesAdapter != null)
            rvMessages?.scrollToPosition(messagesAdapter?.itemCount?.minus(1)!!)
```

for this I have also used DiffUtil but it is also reproducing same behaviour

```
 fun notifyChanges(oldList: List<AllMessages>, newList: List<AllMessages>) {

        val diff = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(object : DiffUtil.Callback() {
            override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean {
                return oldList[oldItemPosition].getChatId() == newList[newItemPosition].getChatId()
            }

            override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean {
                return oldList[oldItemPosition] == newList[newItemPosition]
            }

            override fun getOldListSize() = oldList.size
            override fun getNewListSize() = newList.size
        })

        rvMessages?.recycledViewPool?.clear()

        messagesAdapter?.let { diff.dispatchUpdatesTo(it) }
        // moveToBottom(2)

    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: use `notifyItemInserted` and `notifyItemRangeInserted`

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged is traversing the whole list to update items and causes all of them to redraw. To prevent this you can use [notify* methods of RecyclerView.Adapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyItemInserted(int)), but be careful to ensure that calls to notify* methods match state of your list perfectly

Comment: @denvercoder9 tried but same thing happening. Like if previous blocking time was 4s then these functions just minimizing it to 3s to 2s.